# How bad are bent pins from ICs?

Tags: integrated-circuit, ic-leg

Regularly I buy ICs from China so I know there can be differences in shipping.
Mostly ICs are sent in either plastic IC storage tubes, and mostly stuck on foam. However, today I got them without any protection like this. I got one extra, but as can be seen at least 3 are quite badly bent. Although it seems bad, after straightening them with some pliers I could easily put them in a breadboard and after removing them from the breadboard they look more or less straight.

I am just wondering about the implications of bending (the only thing I can think of is because they have been bent, they might break when the legs are bent again I will prevent of course), but maybe I can get in trouble:

1. When soldering them?
2. Less conductivity?
3. Heating problems?
4. Anything else?

[image]

Comment: The tin-plated steel is good for 1 bend cycle then very brittle,, indicates handling was poor and expect possible ESD wounds ( leakage)

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Thanks for the remark about ESD.

Comment: I would hesitate to plug these chips into sockets, maybe not even into breadboards. Probably OK to solder. If a pin breaks while soldering, its toast anyway - attack it with snips to remove already-soldered legs. Not likely a problem regarding conductivity, but heat conductivity might be compromised.

Comment: @glen_geek Good point about sockets indeed; I hope you mean that the problem in breadboards might be that a leg is broken off while inside a breadboard (guess I take that risk, since I guess it will be more used on breadboards than in something real, as I'm still in the learning phase ).

Comment: From your photo, these pins might break away where they neck-down from the fat lead-frame to the skinny pin. If they break right at the epoxy (been there), its toast. Otherwise, if its a precious one-only chip, you can solder on a replacement pin from a resistor lead, or a #24 wire to the fat stub (been there too).

Comment: @glen_geek I don't think I will try to fix them when needed, they just were 40 cents per piece.

Comment: This [IC tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBuRv.png) is what you want. That one is maybe 45 yrs old and cost me a couple of dollars then (250ppm of a typical new car.) [Excelta](https://www.excelta.com/medium-wide-nose-508b-us) makes something kind of similar, but closer to 6000ppm of a new car now.) (US referenced, granted.)

Comment: I used exactly that tool, that means the pliers .. not the oscilloscope :-), do you think the color of the tool matters? (just kidding).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Know where to get any more of them?? (The old one, I mean, if that's what you recognized. I can only find really expensive tools such as from Excelta and they are overly complex, besides. Mine is getting a little old now and I wouldn't mind replacing it.)

Comment: @jonk Sorry I thought you were making a joke (meaning you meant just to use a plain pliers, which is what I did). But I think you mean a plier with flat insides. I used something like this: https://www.wildetool.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/085432053237.png ... maybe not so perfect as your pliers but good enough for those few ICs I had to fix.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers No Way! That's what I might use in emergencies when I didn't have the right tool for the job. I had boxes of ICs I'd recovered from tossed equipment (back when I had no money to spend and was just interested in wire-wrapping my own small computer using 74LS) to straighten out.

Comment: @jonk sorry to disappoint you than, I used some pliers LOOKING like the picture you send, but if you use a long enough 'normal'  flat pliers I guess you could easily straighten until DIP16 or even more.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers After using the ones I showed for so many years, I wouldn't do without them. Saved time because the tool is designed for DIP and all leads go perfectly lined up. Those particular ones used to be common. Today? Not so much. I should have bought more than one. (Though I'm not spending much time these days doing that kind of stuff, it's still nice to have a pair to show what we used to use back in the day or for the rare occasion when something happens accidentally and you need the tool.)

Comment: @jonk I thought it were flat pliers, but it seems (or you mean) it has small 'gaps'  for the IC legs right? That's indeed cool. Guess since DIP is not really popular for professional purposes anymore, and most hobbyists (like me) don't want to buy such 'specific'  tools I can imagine they are hard to find. I used simple pliers and now they fit in a breadboard again but after taking them out you can see they are not fully straight (but good enough for me).

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, the only problem would be a weakening of the pin where it was bent - this may lead to the pin breaking at that point if it is bent back and forth several times.  As long as the pin doesn't break off, the part should work.

Comment: Good to see that (and easy to verify when it happens).

Comment: The tolerance to bending depends on quality/malleability of alloy used for pins. Some junk ICs break off  (or develop visible cracks) after one cycle... However, if covered with solder, they should work for a prototype.